# CakePHP - Add custom values to User Object

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have added 4 more columns to my CakePHP Users table and I am trying to figure out how I can include these columns in the `$this->Auth->user()` object.

I've added the column information to my Users Model and Entity but still no joy. Currently my user object looks like this;

```
[
    'id' => (int) 1,
    'username' => 'admin',
    'name' => 'Web Admin',
    'email' => 'webteam@',
    'role' => 'admin',
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2016-02-09T16:04:46+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2016-02-12T08:53:16+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    }
]
```

Where is this object created and is there a way I can add my custom values to it, without editing core CakePHP files?

Thanks for your help .

Comment: Waits for ndm to check his newest question list..... ;)

Comment: Did  you try turning on debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the built-in authenticators will fetch all fields in the tables schema.

You most probably just forgot to clear your cache (`tmp/cache/models`), which you should do whenever you make changes to your schemas.

In case one would want to specify what fields are being fetched, a custom finder would be needed.

See **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Customizing Find Query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'finder' => 'auth'
        ]
    ],
]);
```

In your `UsersTable` class

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->select(['id', 'username', 'password', 'column_x', 'column_y']);
}
```

It should be noted that the fields required for authentication must always be included, ie like `username` and `password`!